# C STRUCT strcopy EASY BEGINNER PROGRAM - can't fix compiling errors

Tags: c, string, struct, compilation, compiler-errors

So I've just started programming in C a few days ago and now I'm trying to learn structs.

I have this program but unfortunately I does not compile for some reason. I've spent a lot of time trying to fix it but I cannot seem to find anything wrong with it.

Here are the compiling errors I'm getting:

```
arrays.c:21: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
arrays.c: In function ‘insert’:
arrays.c:26: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘strcpy’
/usr/include/string.h:128: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘struct person’
arrays.c:32: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
arrays.c: In function ‘main’:
arrays.c:46: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
arrays.c:46: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
arrays.c:46: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
```

**I'm not sure what's wrong with my code, I'm even getting errors for my main function (line 46)**

Here is my full program code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

/* these arrays are just used to give the parameters to 'insert',
   to create the 'people' array */

#define HOW_MANY 7
char *names[HOW_MANY]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
              "Harriet"};
int ages[HOW_MANY]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};


/* declare your struct for a person here */
struct person
{ 
    char name [32];
    int age;
} 

static void insert (struct person people[], char *name, int age)
{
  static int nextfreeplace = 0;
  static int nextinsert = 0;
  /* put name and age into the next free place in the array parameter here */
  strcpy(people[nextfreeplace],name);
  people[nextfreeplace].age = age;

  /* modify nextfreeplace here */
  nextfreeplace = nextfreeplace + 1;
  nextinsert = nextinsert + 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  /* declare the people array here */
  struct person people[12]; 

  int i;
  for (i =0; i < HOW_MANY; i++) 
  {
    insert (people, names[i], ages[i]);
  }

  /* print the people array here*/
  for (i =0; i < HOW_MANY); i++)
  {
     printf("%s\n", people[i].name);
     printf("%d\n", people[i].age);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: **STOP** deleting the code from your question.   I've rolled back your changes twice now.  The code is 100% RELEVANT to your question and the answers you received.  When you delete it, it appears that you are trying to ***hide*** your question from your professor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a semicolon after your `struct` declaration:

```
struct person
{ 
    char name [32];
    int age;
}; /* <-- here */
```

You also need to correct your `strcpy()` call to use the `name` field:

```
strcpy(people[nextfreeplace].name, name);
```

And you have a stray `)` in a `for` loop:

```
for (i =0; i < HOW_MANY); i++)
```

... should be:

```
for (i =0; i < HOW_MANY; i++)
```

Comment: Thx a lot Fred! This fixed my issue I've had with my program.

Comment: Your answer was really really good - short but straight to the subject and explicit enough for me to understand my errors! Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 2):

strcpy(people[nextfreeplace].name,name);

will solve you major problem in the question

Answer (score 1):

- Line 19, expected ';' after struct
- Line 46: expected ';' in 'for' statement specifier, expected ';'    after expression, for loop has empty body
- Line 26 passing 'struct person' to parameter of incompatible type    'const void *'

Basically, add a ; after the closing brace of your struct.
Your for loop has a stray ) in it.
The latter is more complex.

Comment: Actually, the line 26 one isn't that complex. It just needs the field name of the struct. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
char *names[]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
          "Harriet"};
int ages[]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};
```

an idea would be to do this:

```
char *names[]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
          "Harriet", 0}; //notice the 0
for(int i=0;names[i];i++)
{
  printf("%s",names[i]);
}
```

but i'm not sure it's the best implementation.

Comment: I'm confused. Why did you omit HOW_MANY? I need to use that to define the number of names and ages I am using, which in my case is "7". Besides, this didn't fix any of my errors.

Comment: when you enumerate the elements in the array, you must not include how long the array is, the compiler will figure this by itself. I believe that you don't have access to that value, to fix this you add a NULL at the end of the list so you know when to stop. Someone should correct me on this

Comment: Specifying the number of elements is not erroneous, unless you provide more initialisers than the number of elements. If you can know the number of elements ahead of time that is a better way than putting a 0 at the end.

Comment: @titus: You are incorrect. You certainly may name the size of the array along with the initialization.

Comment: is there a way to know how many elements you actually have in the enumerated list?

Comment: There is. The compiler knows how long an array is, as long as it's still an array and hasn't decayed into a pointer. `sizeof(name) / sizeof(*name)` will give the length of the array.

Comment: i mean `int array[100]={1,2,3}; sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)` will give me 100, i would like to get 3 (the actual number of elements)

Comment: @titus: If you leave out the 100, you'll get 3. With it, I think the extra 97 elements will be zero initialized.